# Is there an R library for zooming in and out a plot?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

My question is if there is an R library similar to plotly to apply on a shiny application that allows zooming in and out of the plots. This is an example of what i would like to do, the first plot is this histogram [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LadYi.jpg), from that i want with a mouse click on BMW diagram to zoom in for having a better understanding of BMW sales and a more detailed plot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3fWz.jpg), also from this plot to zoom in again that lead to a more detailed plot like this [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSTw5.jpg).

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If this is for a Shiny app, you can use the JavaScript library **panzoom**. Search for "panzoom" in my answers.

Comment: The feature you are looking is commonly called "drill down" or something like that rather than zooming, if you are looking for some better luck googling.

Comment: Section 17.4.1 shows an example in plotly. But there may be more streamlined ways. https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#advanced-applications

Comment: yep, feature I am looking for is 'drill down'. Thank you both for answering my question